# If I have an O(n + m) time complexity where n >= m, can I simplify it to O(n)?

Tags: time, big-o

Title.

I have an algorithm which does two sets of operations. The first part iterates n times, and the second iterates m times. n is always >= m. Does this mean that I should simplify it to O(n)?

Comment: quickly answer , yes! it's big O mean.

Answer (score 2):

If `m` be always less than or equal to `n`, then the following should hold true:

```
O(n + m)
O(n + n)
O(2*n)
O(n)
```